# Ajax request pass data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to send an array in Ajax data request, but I the output that I get display `items[..]`, How to get rid of it, so I can only fetch variable inside it?

[image]

```js
var columnName = 'accountLedgerID';
var gridDataArray = $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data();

var items = {
  method: "updateSequence",
  this_propertyID: $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
  this_length: gridDataArray.length,
};
for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray.length; i++ ) {    
  items["sequence_" + i] = i;
  items["accLedgerID_" + i] = gridDataArray[i][columnName]; 
}


$.ajax({
  url: "./getLedgerManagement.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {
   //items - display a same result as below
   items:items
  },
  sucess: function(data){
    console.log('success')
  }
});
```

I expect it return data like this.

```
method: "updateSequence"
this_propertyID: "1"
this_length: 23
sequence_0: 0
accLedgerID_0: "LA26"
sequence_1: 1
accLedgerID_1: "LA8"
sequence_2: 2
accLedgerID_2: "LA29"
sequence_3: 3
accLedgerID_3: "LA2"
.....
```

Comment: What sort of data is your PHP script expecting? Are you wanting to use `$_POST['method']`, `$_POST['this_propertyID']`, etc or something else? If the former, all you need is `data: items` instead of `data: { items: items }`

Comment: method: `updateSequence` is a function that will be called in php. And within the function I will fetch all this data's. For example `$propertyID = (isset($_POST['this_propertyID']) ? $_POST['this_propertyID'] : '');` and run loop for `sequence_X` and `accLedgerID_X`

Comment: That's not really what I asked you but I think my suggestion should get you were you want to go. Have you tried it?

Comment: omg.. I miss the curly brackets `{}`.. Thanks

Comment: Quick tip: In PHP 7 you can use `$propertyID = $_POST['this_propertyID'] ?? '';`